# Unable to get data attribute value in jquery using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am working with Jquery and php,I have text box and i am trying to pass
"data attribute" (data-vals) value using jquery but i am getting "undefined" as response,
Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
<input type='text' name='postcmnt' class='postcmnt' value='" + str + "' data-vals='123' onkeydown='search(this)' />
<script>
function search(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
            var valss=$(this).data('vals');
            alert('attribute value is '+valss); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the output of "console.log(ele)"

Comment: @SachinVairagi: i am getting following value

"[object HTMLInputElement]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use `on` `keypress` with `class` `postcmnt` or with `input`

```js
$('.postcmnt').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var _t = $(this);
    if(code==13){
        var valss=_t.data('vals');
        var inputVal=_t.val();
         alert('attribute value is '+valss);
         alert('input value is '+inputVal);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='postcmnt' class='postcmnt' value='abc' data-vals='123'/>
```

Comment: But how can i get current texbox value ( which i entered) ?

Comment: @Nisha check it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this -

```
<input type='text' name='postcmnt' class='postcmnt' value='' data-id="123" onkeydown="search(this)" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function search(ele) {
    
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log(ele.getAttribute("data-id")); 
    }
}
</script>
```